# Trouble with Android UI: main theme does not match with popups' theme

Tags: android, android-theme

So I am still working on my messaging app, and I have successfully implemented a few popups on my own, but then they don't turn out exactly as I want...

[image]

[image]

The theme is supposed to be strictly black text on white background, zero transparency (`Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`). While I have no problems whatsoever in the activity itself, my trouble is with the popups, whose theme does not seem to match as I expected. Can anybody tell me how to fix these?

Comment: It looks like I figured out the answer to the first figure. I just have to add [`PopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) to my popup menu's code. Still stumped at the dialog, though. I'll try to browse around for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after much trial and error, I only had to force the views to use specific styles/themes.

For the popup menu (PopupWindow):

```
menu.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            android.R.color.background_light));
```

For the dialog (DialogFragment), it's...:

```
setStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ListView, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
```

...Or it just corrected itself.